# Vertical Dropdown menu with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sass

I'm trying to create a drop down menu using ul and li a. My actual problem is, When I click on a li a, the previous li a will be closed

How can we use jQuery or JavaScript to close the previous drop-down menu by clicking on each drop-down menu?

**This is my code:**

EXAPMLE :
https://codepen.io/meysamrad/pen/QWYxoXG

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu__main .dropdown__link").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().find(".dropdown__link, .dropdown__list, .dropdown__arrow, .dropdown__text").toggleClass("active");
  });
  $(".menu__main .sub__link").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().find(".sub__link, .sub__list, .sub__arrow, .sub__text").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
/*compiled CSS*/
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
}

main {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.svg-arrow {
  display: none;
}

.menu__vtl ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu__vtl ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul li a svg {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  transition: rotate 0.1s, transform 0.4s ease-out;
  fill: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul li a span {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.menu__vtl ul li .single__text, .menu__vtl ul li .dropdown__text, .menu__vtl ul li .dropdown__list__text, .menu__vtl ul li .sub__text {
  flex: 1;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list, .menu__vtl ul .sub__list {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list .sub a svg {
  fill: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list .sub .sub__list li a {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list__link {
  gap: 15px;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list__link::before {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 100% !important;
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list, .menu__vtl ul .sub__list {
  display: none;
}
.menu__vtl ul .active.dropdown__list, .menu__vtl ul .active.sub__list {
  display: block;
}
.menu__vtl ul .single__link:hover, .menu__vtl ul .dropdown__link:hover, .menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list__link:hover, .menu__vtl ul .sub__link:hover, .menu__vtl ul .sub__list__link:hover {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  color: var(--txt-white);
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__link:hover .dropdown__arrow, .menu__vtl ul .sub__link:hover .sub__arrow {
  fill: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul .single__link .single__text.active, .menu__vtl ul .dropdown__link .dropdown__text.active, .menu__vtl ul .sub__link .sub__text.active {
  color: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__link.active {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__link.active .dropdown__arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  fill: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__link.active .dropdown__text {
  color: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__list__link.active .dropdown__list__text {
  color: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul .dropdown__link .dropdown__arrow.active, .menu__vtl ul .sub__link .sub__arrow.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  fill: #000;
}
.menu__vtl ul .sub__link .sub__arrow.active {
  transform: rotate(134deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sass.js/0.6.2/sass.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu__main menu__vtl">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="single">
            <a href="#" class="single__link">
                <span class="single__text">test</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active dropdown__link">
                <span class="dropdown__text">test</span>
                <svg class="dropdown__arrow"><use href="#arrow-down"></use></svg>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown__list">
                <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown__list__link">
                        <span class="dropdown__list__text">test</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="#" class="sub__link">
                        <span class="sub__text">test</span>
                        <svg class="sub__arrow"><use href="#arrow-add"></use></svg>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub__list">
                        <li class="sub__list__item">
                            <a href="#" class="sub__list__link">test</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub__list__item">
                            <a href="#" class="sub__list__link">test</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Please tell me the best solution for jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Would it be possible to see this  in an SO snippet? I could help you better..

Comment: https://codepen.io/meysamrad/pen/QWYxoXG

Comment: I have already made this kind of menu before. And I suspect there is other answers on SO for this kind of menu... see here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943665/how-can-i-collapse-vanilla-js-multi-level-menu-when-other-menu-is-opened/69950577#69950577